# unset session on Zend framework II .how to clear my session?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, containers

I have my session stored in login action using zend session container .

```
 $sessionTimer = new Container('timer');
 $sessionTimer->username=$data['user_name'];
```

and I want my session clear on logout action and I used 
Zend_Session::destroy(); but it didn't work as expected .I googled it and use almost everything they said ..but still doesn't work for me ...Any idea  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear a session you use the following, call it on your logout.php script:

```
$sessionTimer->getManager()->getStorage()->clear('timer');
```

I believe you can treat it like an array as well, so unset($_SESSION['timer']); should work.